# Why are leaving shabbos before coming into it

Tags: shabbat-songs, kol-mikadesh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Kol Mekadesh - sung Friday Night - המאחרים לצאת מן השבת וממהרים לבא](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/8756/kol-mekadesh-sung-friday-night)

> המאחרים לצאת מן השבת וממהרים לבוא

Loosely translated those who rush to leave the Shabbos and rush towards its coming.
Why are we mentioning leaving Shabbos before coming into it?